# PHP Sting Function Zip+4 to Zip

Tags: php, string

I'm looking to convert US Format Zip Code 00000-1234 to 00000.  But the zip may also be Canadian, UK or the World for that matter.

So I guess a sanity check would be that you have 5 digits all 0-9 followed by a dash followed by 4 digits 0-9.  If that fails leave the string alone if it passes trim off everything to the Right of the 5th digit.

Greg :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
preg_replace('/(\d{5})\-\d{4}/', '$1', $zipcode);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$output = preg_replace('!\(d{5})-\d{4}!', '$1', $input);
```